# Is it right say Invest on?

Tags: grammar, differences, word-usage

Is it correct idiomatically to say "invest on?" For example, "Invest on Peter " [a person].

Comment: This question is probably better for English Language Learners Stack Exchange (http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, Invest **in** would be preferred.

Comment: Invest in someone vs invest on someone: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invest+in+someone%2C+invest+on+someone+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvest%20in%20someone%3B%2Cc0